# How to use deep link to navigate between screens within the app in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-deep-link

I want to switch between screens within the application with a deep link, but I could not fully understand the deep link structure, there is not much detailed explanation.It is generally used to switch from one app to another or to switch from a website URL, but I have not seen the use of deeplinks to switch between screens within the application.What I want to do is When I click on the items in HomeScreen, I need to go to DetailScreen with deeplink. For example, when I click on the pasta content on HomeScreen, I want to go to the detail of the pasta using the deep link of this content. However, the detail page can be accessed from several screens and on some screens I send the objectId instead of the deep link. I wrote a code like this, but I couldn't solve it . Can onyone help me who used deeplink like this before ?

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.bottomBarNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.HomeScreen.route,
        route = BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE
    ){

        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.HomeScreen.route){
            HomeRoute(navHostController)
        }
```

---

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.healthNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController
) {

    navigation(
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.HealthScreen.route,
        route = BOTTOM_BAR_HEALTH_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "${HealthScreen.HealthFoodDetailScreen.route}?$OBJECT_ID={$OBJECT_ID}?$DEEPLINK_URI={$DEEPLINK_URI}",
            deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "$DEEPLINK_URI/{$OBJECT_ID}"
                action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            }),
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(name = OBJECT_ID) {
                    type = NavType.IntType
                },
                navArgument(name = DEEPLINK_URI) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = ""
                }
            )) { backStackEntry ->

            FoodDetailRoute(navHostController = navHostController)
        }
```

**HomeScreen Item component**

```
 Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(160.dp)
                .clickable {
                    //I want to navigate to detail with deeplink when user click 
                },
```

**Manifest**

```
 <application
        .
        .
        .>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="compose"
                android:scheme="example" />
        </intent-filter> 
             ...
```

Comment: I guess this video can help you solve the issue. [deep linking](https://youtu.be/z6VlP0o_sDc?si=KGiJT8emKZLAOz5V)